# Why is querying mongoDB by time range not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timestamp, date-format

I'm trying to extract data from a `mongoDB` that has some time properties within a specific time interval. The filter is defined by the request query string:

```
var getLessonByParams = function (req, res, next){
    console.log(req.query.timeFrom);    
    if(req.query.timeFrom !== undefined){
        req.query.timeFrom = {$gte: req.query.timeFrom};
    }
    if(req.query.timeTo !== undefined){
        req.query.timeTo = {$lte: req.query.timeTo};
    }
    console.log(req.query);         
    LessonModel.find(req.query,  function (err, lessons){
        if(!err){           
            res.status(200).json(lessons);
        }
        else{
            return next(errorHelper(err));
        }
    });
};
```

Something is obviously wrong though, since it returns data from before the time I specified, as well as doesn't return some records that it should return. Any ideas?

Edit:

Incoming query variable:

```
2015-08-01T01:15:00.000Z
```

Query after substituting `gte`:

```
{ timeFrom: { '$gte': Sat Aug 01 2015 03:15:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) } }
```

Mongoose output:

```
Mongoose: lessons.find({ timeFrom: { '$gte': new Date("Sat, 01 Aug 2015 01:15:00 GMT") } }) { fields: undefined }
```

Documents I'm working with:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d1db90daea17d3e90a3c4d"),    
"timeFrom" : ISODate("2015-08-01T01:15:00.000Z"),
"timeTo" : ISODate("2015-08-01T02:15:00.000Z")
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d1ee1cdaea17d3e90a3c53"),
"timeFrom" : ISODate("2015-08-01T01:45:00.000Z"),
"timeTo" : ISODate("2015-08-01T02:30:00.000Z")
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d73b10de2699c615778bd8"),

"timeTo" : "2015-08-02T06:45:00.000Z",
"timeFrom" : "2015-08-02T05:15:00.000Z",

}
```

Comment: How is your schema on the  model specified? Are the fields here set as `Date`? What is the string input coming in for the request? Log as much as you can and inpect those values. Also not really a "range" if it is in fact on two different fields. Your logic here may be incorrect considering that.

Comment: Yes, it is `Date`. See my edits

Comment: My intention is to have the `timeFrom` to `timeTo` range within the range specified in the request query.

Comment: Give people some sample documents that should be selected. That way it makes it easier for others to debug with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out (and as I suspected) it was a format issue. Some of the records have those dates stored as strings, while they should be stored as `ISODate`.